# How to find memory leak in a C++ code/project?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I am a C++ programmer on the Windows platform. I am using Visual Studio 2008.

I usually end up in the code with memory leaks.

Normally I find the memory leak by inspecting the code, but it is cumbersome and is not always a good approach.

Since I can't afford a paid memory leak detection tool, I wanted you guys to suggest the best possible ways to avoid memory leaks.

1. I want to the know how the programmer can find memory leaks.
2. Is there any standard or procedure one should follow to ensure there is no memory leak in the program?

Comment: "I usually end up in the code with memory leak."  If you use automatic variables, containers, and smart pointers (and follow best practices for using smart pointers), memory leaks should be extremely rare.  Remember, [in almost all cases, you should use automatic resource management](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681455/what-is-the-philosophy-of-managing-memory-in-c).

Comment: Duplicates issues covered by several questions, like  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502799/memory-leak-tool-for-c-under-windows and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820223/visual-c-memory-leak-detection

Comment: @Hostile Fork: "how can one avoid to *usually* end up in code with memory leaks" is not covered by those answers.

Comment: @Doc Brown: Didn't feel like looking that up too, but it's all covered elsewhere, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45627/how-do-you-detect-avoid-memory-leaks-in-your-unmanaged-code

Comment: @Hostile Fork: of course, I feel that's a much better link. Thanks!

Comment: Here is a new tool to find memory leaks:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/11/finding-memory-leaks-on-solaris-is-no.html

Comment: DIY Leak detector: You could put a suspect code in an infinite loop and then open up a task manager, typically even a small leak will fill up the memory in seconds or minutes (That depends on your code complexity and your CPU). If that doesn't happen, that piece of code is probably not leaking.

Answer (score 359, accepted):

**Instructions**

Things You'll Need

- Proficiency in C++
- C++ compiler
- Debugger and other investigative software tools

## 1

Understand the operator basics. The C++ operator `new` allocates heap memory. The `delete` operator frees heap memory. For every `new`, you should use a `delete` so that you free the same memory you allocated:

```
char* str = new char [30]; // Allocate 30 bytes to house a string.

delete [] str; // Clear those 30 bytes and make str point nowhere.
```

## 2

Reallocate memory only if you've deleted. In the code below, `str` acquires a new address with the second allocation. The first address is lost irretrievably, and so are the 30 bytes that it pointed to. Now they're impossible to free, and you have a memory leak:

```
char* str = new char [30]; // Give str a memory address.

// delete [] str; // Remove the first comment marking in this line to correct.

str = new char [60]; /* Give str another memory address with
                                                    the first one gone forever.*/

delete [] str; // This deletes the 60 bytes, not just the first 30.
```

## 3

Watch those pointer assignments. Every dynamic variable (allocated memory on the heap) needs to be associated with a pointer. When a dynamic variable becomes disassociated from its pointer(s), it becomes impossible to erase. Again, this results in a memory leak:

```
char* str1 = new char [30];

char* str2 = new char [40];

strcpy(str1, "Memory leak");

str2 = str1; // Bad! Now the 40 bytes are impossible to free.

delete [] str2; // This deletes the 30 bytes.

delete [] str1; // Possible access violation. What a disaster!
```

## 4

Be careful with local pointers. A pointer you declare in a function is allocated on the stack, but the dynamic variable it points to is allocated on the heap. If you don't delete it, it will persist after the program exits from the function:

```
void Leak(int x){

char* p = new char [x];

// delete [] p; // Remove the first comment marking to correct.

}
```

## 5

Pay attention to the square braces after "delete." Use `delete` by itself to free a single object. Use `delete []` with square brackets to free a heap array. Don't do something like this:

```
char* one = new char;

delete [] one; // Wrong

char* many = new char [30];

delete many; // Wrong!
```

## 6

If the leak yet allowed - I'm usually seeking it with deleaker (check it here: http://deleaker.com).

Comment: sorry for question-comment but what about function parameters without pointers? `someFunction("some parameter")` do I have to delete `"some parameter"` in the `someFunction`, after the function call, or are these automatically deleted?

Comment: thank you for the link to Deleaker, this is a really handy tool with a neat integration into visual studio. I could save a lot of time using it. pointed me to the lines where I allocated memory and did not free it. Great. And it is cheap, compared with other memory leak finders I found.

Comment: @ john smith plz explan what is the proper way to handle cases similar to case 3;
str2 = str1; // Bad! Now the 40 bytes are impossible to free.
how to delete str 1 then ??

Comment: What if we use value type like char*, int, float,... and struct like Vector, CString, and don't use any 'new' operator at all, it won't cause memory leak, is it right?

Comment: I'm just here to say I haven't touched c++ in close to 14 years...but I am proud to say I understood and remember how to do all of this thanks to a c++ book I still possess and read when I'm bored with c#.  That book is Scott Mitchell's Effective C++.  God I loved that book. Thanks Scott!

Comment: @JonH: Scott **Meyers**, surely?

Comment: Yes that scott sorry!

Answer (score 37):

You can use some techniques in your code to detect memory leak. The most common and most easy way to detect is, define a macro say, DEBUG_NEW and use it, along with predefined macros like `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` to locate the memory leak in your code. These predefined macros tell you the file and line number of memory leaks.

DEBUG_NEW is just a MACRO which is usually defined as:

```
#define DEBUG_NEW new(__FILE__, __LINE__)
#define new DEBUG_NEW
```

So that wherever you use `new`, it also can keep track of the file and line number which could be used to locate memory leak in your program.

And `__FILE__`, `__LINE__` are [predefined macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which evaluate to the filename and line number respectively where you use them!

Read the following article which explains the technique of using DEBUG_NEW with other interesting macros, very beautifully:

[A Cross-Platform Memory Leak Detector](http://wyw.dcweb.cn/leakage.htm)

---

From [Wikpedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debug_new),

> Debug_new refers to a technique in C++
>   to overload and/or redefine operator
>   new and operator delete in order to
>   intercept the memory allocation and
>   deallocation calls, and thus debug a
>   program for memory usage. **It often
>   involves defining a macro named
>   DEBUG_NEW, and makes new become
>   something like new(_*FILE*_, _*LINE*_)
>   to record the file/line information on
>   allocation.** Microsoft Visual C++ uses
>   this technique in its Microsoft
>   Foundation Classes. There are some
>   ways to extend this method to avoid
>   using macro redefinition while still
>   able to display the file/line
>   information on some platforms. There
>   are many inherent limitations to this
>   method. It applies only to C++, and
>   cannot catch memory leaks by C
>   functions like malloc. However, it can
>   be very simple to use and also very
>   fast, when compared to some more
>   complete memory debugger solutions.

Comment: this `#define` will mess up with overloaded `operator new` and generate compiler errors. Even if you succeed to overcome that then still the overloaded functions will not be addressed. Though the technique is good, it needs lot of code changes sometimes.

Comment: @iammilind: Of course, this technique is not all-cure solution of all set of problems and surely isn't applicable in all situations.

Comment: @Chris_vr: `auto_ptr` will not work with standard containers such as `std::vector`, `std::list` etc. See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111478/why-is-it-wrong-to-use-stdauto-ptr-with-stl-containers

Comment: Okay cool.  __FILE__ and line are described.  What is `operator new` and what are these versions of it that you are using?

Comment: can u edit ur answer to add an example & result for easy understanding.

Answer (score 32):

**Running "Valgrind" can:**

1) **Help Identify Memory Leaks** - show you how many memory leaks you have, and point out to the lines in the code where the leaked memory was allocated.

2) **Point out wrong attempts to free memory** (e.g. improper call of `delete`)

**Instructions for using "Valgrind"**

1) Get valgrind [here](http://www.valgrind.org/downloads/current.html).

2) Compile your code with `-g` flag

3) In your shell run:

```
valgrind --leak-check=yes myprog arg1 arg2
```

Where "myprog" is your compiled program and `arg1`, `arg2` your programme's arguments.

4) The result is a list of calls to `malloc`/`new` that did not have subsequent calls to free delete.

**For example:**

```
==4230==    at 0x1B977DD0: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:136)

==4230==    by 0x804990F: main (example.c:6)
```

Tells you in which line the `malloc` (that was not freed) was called.

As Pointed out by others, make sure that for every `new`/`malloc` call, you have a subsequent `delete`/`free` call.

Answer (score 17):

**A survey of automatic memory leak checkers**

In this answer, I compare several different memory leak checkers in a simple easy to understand memory leak example.

Before anything, see this huge table in the ASan wiki which compares all tools known to man: https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerComparisonOfMemoryTools/d06210f759fec97066888e5f27c7e722832b0924

The example analyzed will be:

main.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void * my_malloc(size_t n) {
    return malloc(n);
}

void leaky(size_t n, int do_leak) {
    void *p = my_malloc(n);
    if (!do_leak) {
        free(p);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    leaky(0x10, 0);
    leaky(0x10, 1);
    leaky(0x100, 0);
    leaky(0x100, 1);
    leaky(0x1000, 0);
    leaky(0x1000, 1);
}
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/31473ebb398f9a2b638b04c14b456ffa312ac667/userland/c/memory_leak.c).

We will try to see how clearly do the different tools point us to the leaky calls.

**tcmalloc from gperftools by Google**

https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools

Usage on Ubuntu 19.04:

```
sudo apt-get install google-perftools
gcc -ggdb3 -o main.out main.c -ltcmalloc
PPROF_PATH=/usr/bin/google-pprof \
  HEAPCHECK=normal \
  HEAPPROFILE=ble \
  ./main.out \
;
google-pprof main.out ble.0001.heap --text
```

The output of the program run contains the memory leak analysis:

```
WARNING: Perftools heap leak checker is active -- Performance may suffer
Starting tracking the heap
Dumping heap profile to ble.0001.heap (Exiting, 4 kB in use)
Have memory regions w/o callers: might report false leaks
Leak check _main_ detected leaks of 272 bytes in 2 objects
The 2 largest leaks:
Using local file ./main.out.
Leak of 256 bytes in 1 objects allocated from:
        @ 555bf6e5815d my_malloc
        @ 555bf6e5817a leaky
        @ 555bf6e581d3 main
        @ 7f71e88c9b6b __libc_start_main
        @ 555bf6e5808a _start
Leak of 16 bytes in 1 objects allocated from:
        @ 555bf6e5815d my_malloc
        @ 555bf6e5817a leaky
        @ 555bf6e581b5 main
        @ 7f71e88c9b6b __libc_start_main
        @ 555bf6e5808a _start


If the preceding stack traces are not enough to find the leaks, try running THIS shell command:

pprof ./main.out "/tmp/main.out.24744._main_-end.heap" --inuse_objects --lines --heapcheck  --edgefraction=1e-10 --nodefraction=1e-10 --gv

If you are still puzzled about why the leaks are there, try rerunning this program with HEAP_CHECK_TEST_POINTER_ALIGNMENT=1 and/or with HEAP_CHECK_MAX_POINTER_OFFSET=-1
If the leak report occurs in a small fraction of runs, try running with TCMALLOC_MAX_FREE_QUEUE_SIZE of few hundred MB or with TCMALLOC_RECLAIM_MEMORY=false, it might help find leaks more re
Exiting with error code (instead of crashing) because of whole-program memory leaks
```

and the output of `google-pprof` contains the heap usage analysis:

```
Using local file main.out.
Using local file ble.0001.heap.
Total: 0.0 MB
     0.0 100.0% 100.0%      0.0 100.0% my_malloc
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0 100.0% __libc_start_main
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0 100.0% _start
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0 100.0% leaky
     0.0   0.0% 100.0%      0.0 100.0% main
```

The output points us to two of the three leaks:

```
Leak of 256 bytes in 1 objects allocated from:
        @ 555bf6e5815d my_malloc
        @ 555bf6e5817a leaky
        @ 555bf6e581d3 main
        @ 7f71e88c9b6b __libc_start_main
        @ 555bf6e5808a _start
Leak of 16 bytes in 1 objects allocated from:
        @ 555bf6e5815d my_malloc
        @ 555bf6e5817a leaky
        @ 555bf6e581b5 main
        @ 7f71e88c9b6b __libc_start_main
        @ 555bf6e5808a _start
```

I'm not sure why the third one didn't show up

In any case, when usually when something leaks, it happens a lot of times, and when I used it on a real project, I just ended up being pointed out to the leaking function very easily.

As mentioned on the output itself, this incurs a significant execution slowdown.

Further documentation at:

- https://gperftools.github.io/gperftools/heap_checker.html
- https://gperftools.github.io/gperftools/heapprofile.html

See also: [How To Use TCMalloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29205141/how-to-use-tcmalloc)

Tested in Ubuntu 19.04, google-perftools 2.5-2.

**Address Sanitizer (ASan) also by Google**

https://github.com/google/sanitizers

Previously mentioned at: [How to find memory leak in a C++ code/project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261201/how-to-find-memory-leak-in-a-c-code-project/28398186#28398186) TODO vs tcmalloc.

This is already integrated into GCC, so you can just do:

```
gcc -fsanitize=address -ggdb3 -o main.out main.c
./main.out
```

and execution outputs:

```
=================================================================
==27223==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 4096 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7fabbefc5448 in malloc (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x10c448)
    #1 0x55bf86c5f17c in my_malloc /home/ciro/test/main.c:4
    #2 0x55bf86c5f199 in leaky /home/ciro/test/main.c:8
    #3 0x55bf86c5f210 in main /home/ciro/test/main.c:20
    #4 0x7fabbecf4b6a in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x26b6a)

Direct leak of 256 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7fabbefc5448 in malloc (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x10c448)
    #1 0x55bf86c5f17c in my_malloc /home/ciro/test/main.c:4
    #2 0x55bf86c5f199 in leaky /home/ciro/test/main.c:8
    #3 0x55bf86c5f1f2 in main /home/ciro/test/main.c:18
    #4 0x7fabbecf4b6a in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x26b6a)

Direct leak of 16 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7fabbefc5448 in malloc (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x10c448)
    #1 0x55bf86c5f17c in my_malloc /home/ciro/test/main.c:4
    #2 0x55bf86c5f199 in leaky /home/ciro/test/main.c:8
    #3 0x55bf86c5f1d4 in main /home/ciro/test/main.c:16
    #4 0x7fabbecf4b6a in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x26b6a)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 4368 byte(s) leaked in 3 allocation(s).
```

which clearly identifies all leaks. Nice!

ASan can also do other cool checks such as out-of-bounds writes: [Stack smashing detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345670/stack-smashing-detected/51897264#51897264)

Tested in Ubuntu 19.04, GCC 8.3.0.

**Valgrind**

http://www.valgrind.org/

Previously mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37661630/895245

Usage:

```
sudo apt-get install valgrind
gcc -ggdb3 -o main.out main.c
valgrind --leak-check=yes ./main.out
```

Output:

```
==32178== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==32178== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==32178== Using Valgrind-3.14.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==32178== Command: ./main.out
==32178== 
==32178== 
==32178== HEAP SUMMARY:
==32178==     in use at exit: 4,368 bytes in 3 blocks
==32178==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 3 frees, 8,736 bytes allocated
==32178== 
==32178== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 3
==32178==    at 0x483874F: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==32178==    by 0x10915C: my_malloc (main.c:4)
==32178==    by 0x109179: leaky (main.c:8)
==32178==    by 0x1091B4: main (main.c:16)
==32178== 
==32178== 256 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 3
==32178==    at 0x483874F: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==32178==    by 0x10915C: my_malloc (main.c:4)
==32178==    by 0x109179: leaky (main.c:8)
==32178==    by 0x1091D2: main (main.c:18)
==32178== 
==32178== 4,096 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 3
==32178==    at 0x483874F: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==32178==    by 0x10915C: my_malloc (main.c:4)
==32178==    by 0x109179: leaky (main.c:8)
==32178==    by 0x1091F0: main (main.c:20)
==32178== 
==32178== LEAK SUMMARY:
==32178==    definitely lost: 4,368 bytes in 3 blocks
==32178==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==32178==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==32178==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==32178==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==32178== 
==32178== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==32178== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

So once again, all leaks were detected.

See also: [How do I use valgrind to find memory leaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134891/how-do-i-use-valgrind-to-find-memory-leaks)

Tested in Ubuntu 19.04, valgrind 3.14.0.

Answer (score 16):

There are some well-known programming techniques that will help you to minimize the risk of getting memory leaks at first hand:

- if you have to do your own dynamic memory allocation, write `new` and `delete` always pairwise, and make sure the allocation/deallocation code is called pairwise
- avoid dynamic memory allocation if you can. For example, use `vector<T> t` whereever possible instead of `T* t = new T[size]`
- use "smart pointers" like boost smart pointers (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm)
- my personal favorite: make sure you have understood the concept of ownership of a pointer, and make sure that everywhere where you use pointers, you know which code entity is the owner
- learn which constructors / assignment operators are automatically created by the C++ compiler, and what that means if you have class that owns a pointer (or what that means if you have a class that contains a pointer to an object it does *not* own).

Comment: I use auto_pointer of a object does that mean it will delete all the other class object pointer inside it.

Comment: @Chris_vr: if you have a specific question about auto_pointer, I would suggest you make a new question, including an example.

Comment: Many posts tell me that vector<> does not guarantee memory being freed upon clear. I personally tested swap stuff etc and I came to the conclusion that vector<> is leaking especially when used dynamically. I don't understand how vector<> can be advised over do-it-yourself dynamic allocation using 'new' and cleanup correctly. In my embedded programs I avoid using vector<> for dynamic stuff because of all the leaks. There I use new or std::list

Comment: I type a second command because of the number of characters. Unfortunately in my embedded c++ I have an old c++ (98?) which does not have shrink_to_fit on a vector... However the embedded program is 100% sure to totally crash when running out of memory using vector<> dynamically

Answer (score 10):

Valgrind
http://valgrind.org/

and

GDB
http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/

Answer (score 9):

1. Download [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009).
2. Use the `gflags` utility to turn on user-mode stack traces.
3. Use [`UMDH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff558947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to take multiple snapshots of your program's memory. Take a snapshot before memory gets allocated, and take a second snapshot after a point at which you believe that your program has leaked memory. You might want to add pauses or prompts in your program to give you a chance to run `UMDH` and take the snapshots.
4. Run `UMDH` again, this time in its mode that does a diff between the two snapshots. It will then generate a report containing the call stacks of suspected memory leaks.
5. Restore your previous `gflags` settings when you're done.

`UMDH` will give you more information than the CRT debug heap because it is watching memory allocations across your entire process; it can even tell you if third-party components are leaking.

Comment: I prefer Deleaker and Valgrind instead of standard profiler

Answer (score 6):

If you use gcc, there's gprof available.

> I wanted to the know how programmer find memory leak

Some uses tools, some does what you do, could also through peer code review

> Is there any standard or procedure one should follow to ensure there is no memory leak in the program

For me: whenever I create dynamically allocated objects, I always put the freeing code after, then fill the code between. This would be OK if you're sure there won't be exceptions in the code between. Otherwise, I make use of try-finally (I don't use C++ frequently).

Comment: some time we can't delete allocated in the constructor.what to do on that occasion.

Answer (score 6):

1. In visual studio, there is a built in detector for memory leak called C Runtime Library. When your program exits after the main function returns, CRT will check the debug heap of your application. if you have any blocks still allocated on the debug heap, then you have memory leak..
2. [This forum](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/how-to-avoid-memory-leakage-c-c-393228/) discusses a few ways to avoid memory leakage in C/C++..

Answer (score 6):

[AddressSanitizer](https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/) (ASan) is a fast memory error detector. 
It finds use-after-free and {heap,stack,global}-buffer overflow bugs in C/C++ programs. It finds:

- Use after free (dangling pointer dereference)
- Heap buffer overflow
- Stack buffer overflow
- Global buffer overflow
- Use after return
- Initialization order bugs

This tool is very fast. The average slowdown of the instrumented program is ~2x.

Comment: See especially [LeakSanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerLeakSanitizer)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the tool Valgrind to detect memory leaks.

Also, to find the leak in a particular function, use exit(0) at the end of the function and then run it with Valgrind

```
`$` valgrind ./your_CPP_program
```

Answer (score 5):

Search your code for occurrences of `new`, and make sure that they all occur within a constructor with a matching delete in a destructor. Make sure that this is the only possibly throwing operation in that constructor. A simple way to do this is to wrap all pointers in `std::auto_ptr`, or `boost::scoped_ptr` (depending on whether or not you need move semantics). For all future code just ensure that every resource is owned by an object that cleans up the resource in its destructor. If you need move semantics then you can upgrade to a compiler that supports r-value references (VS2010 does I believe) and create move constructors. If you don't want to do that then you can use a variety of tricky techniques involving conscientious usage of swap, or try the Boost.Move library.

Comment: it is not always possible to delete the allocated memory in the constructor.How to deal this situation

Comment: @Chris_vr What do you mean? If all your pointer members are `scope_ptr`s, and each is initialised individually then all the ones that were successfully constructed will delete their pointers, and the others will not yet be holding pointers to allocated memory anyway. I will put up an example in a few hours when I get home from work.

Comment: @Chris_vr: if you have a specific example, post it as a new question, so we can discuss it there.

Answer (score 4):

Answering the second part of your question,

> Is there any standard or procedure one should follow to ensure there is no memory leak in the program.

Yes, there is. And this is one of the key differences between C and C++.

In C++, you should never call `new` or `delete` in your user code. [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII) is a very commonly used technique, which pretty much solves the resource management problem. Every resource in your program (a resource is anything that has to be acquired, and then later on, released: file handles, network sockets, database connections, but also plain memory allocations, and in some cases, pairs of API calls (BeginX()/EndX(), LockY(), UnlockY()), should be wrapped in a class, where:

- the constructor *acquires* the resource (by calling `new` if the resource is a memroy allocation)
- the destructor *releases* the resource,
- copying and assignment is either prevented (by making the copy constructor and assignment operators private), or are implemented to work correctly (for example by cloning the underlying resource)

This class is then instantiated locally, on the stack, or as a class member, and *not* by calling `new` and storing a pointer.

You often don't need to define these classes yourself. The standard library containers behave in this way as well, so that any object stored into a `std::vector` gets freed when the vector is destroyed. So again, don't store a pointer into the container (which would require *you* to call `new` and `delete`), but rather the object *itself* (which gives you memory management *for free*). Likewise, smart pointer classes can be used to easily wrap objects that just have to be allocated with `new`, and control their lifetimes.

This means that when the object goes out of scope, it is automatically destroyed, and its resource released and cleaned up.

If you do this consistently throughout your code, you simply won't have any memory leaks. Everything that *could* get leaked is tied to a destructor which is guaranteed to be called when control leaves the scope in which the object was declared.

Comment: if smart pointer  holds a class and that class contain pointer of several other class. when smart goes off does that mean all the pointer inside will be deleted safely.

Comment: @Chris: *Assuming* that the object being pointed to by the smart pointer has a destructor which does the necessary cleanup *or* the object contains members which themselves have destructors to perform the necessary cleanup. In essence, as long as every object takes care of itself (cleaning up after itself when it is destroyed), and as long as every object is stored by value, not as a pointer, then everything that needs to be freed *will* get freed.

Answer (score 4):

[Visual Leak Detector (VLD)](http://vld.codeplex.com/) is a free, robust, open-source memory leak detection system for Visual C++.

> When you run your program under the Visual Studio debugger, Visual Leak Detector will output a memory leak report at the end of your debugging session. The leak report includes the **full call stack** showing how any leaked memory blocks were allocated. Double-click on a line in the call stack to jump to that file and line in the editor window.

If you only have crash dumps, you can use the Windbg `!heap -l` command, it will detect leaked heap blocks. Better open the gflags option: “Create user mode stack trace database”, then you will see the memory allocation call stack.

Answer (score 4):

[MTuner](http://mtuner.net) is a free multi platform memory profiling, leak detection and analysis tool supporting MSVC, GCC and Clang compilers. Features include:

- timeline based history of memory usage and live memory blocks
- powerful memory operation filtering based on heap, memory tag, time range, etc.
- SDK for manual instrumentation with full source code
- continuous integration support through command line usage
- call stack tree and tree map navigation
- much more.

Users can profile any software targeting platforms with GCC or Clang cross
compilers. MTuner comes with built in support for Windows, PlayStation 4 and PlayStation 3 platforms.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's a great tool and can handle the volumes of allocations/deallocations that others cannot.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows you can use [CRT debug heap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1.aspx).

> Is there any standard or procedure one should follow to ensure there is no memory leak in the program.

Yeah, don't use manual memory management (if you ever call `delete` or `delete[]` manually, then you're doing it wrong). Use RAII and smart pointers, limit heap allocations to the absolute minimum (most of the time, automatic variables will suffice).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the tools and methodes provided in the other anwers, static code analysis tools can be used to detect memory leaks (and other issues as well).
A free an robust tool is Cppcheck. But there are a lot of other tools available. [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis) has a list of static code analysis tools.

Answer (score 0):

To avid memory leak one of my senior engineer suggest

1: if you are write code for allocating memory next statement should be free that memory and between write your code

```
int *ptr = new int
// your code 
delete int ;
ptr = NULL;
```

2: Basically, in really good C++ code, you should never call delete yourself to clean up memory that you've allocated: used **Smart Pointers:**`(e.g., std::unique_ptr and std::shared_ptr)`

3. Allocate and de-allocate resources within the constructor and destructor of a class.used **RAII (Resource Acquisition Is Initialization)**consept

4.If you are using containers, make sure to clear them or use smart containers that automatically manage memory.

```
std::vector<int>* myVector = new std::vector<int>;
// ...
myVector->clear();
delete myVector;
```

5. If **consumer producer** case means allocating memory return from function and used by other function make sure that consumer is de-allocating that memory.
6. Avoid Circular Reference while you are using **std::shared_ptr**

Answer (score -1):

Make certain that all the heap memory is successfully freed. There is no need if you never allocate memory on the heap. If you do, count the number of times you malloc memory, and count up the number of time you free memory.

Answer (score -3):

Neither "new" or "delete" should ever be used in application code. Instead, create a new type that uses the manager/worker idiom, in which the manager class allocates and frees memory and forwards all other operations to the worker object.

Unfortunately this is more work than it should be because C++ doesn't have overloading of "operator .". It is even more work in the presence of polymorphism.

But this is worth the effort because you then don't ever have to worry about memory leaks, which means you don't even have to look for them.