# What debugger can check c++ code for memory leaks?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, memory-leaks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to find memory leak in c++ code/project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261201/how-to-find-memory-leak-in-c-code-project)

I would like to ask what debugger should I install in order to check for memory leaks? I have an .a that contains a .cpp and an .h . I used a lot of pointers and references.  Now I would like to test for memory leaks.

I heard about lint. Does this exist?
THX

Comment: You mean [memory leaks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)? Also, here's how I check if something exists: Is there a wikipedia article? Does Google give several relevant results?

Comment: lint is for C. For C++ you can use cppcheck to find some errors: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cppcheck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need memory debugging, memory leak detection, and profiling tool like **[Valgrind](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Valgrind).**
Debuggers don't usually do that.

Comment: i want a program where i can umload my code and debug it...in order to see the memory lack, the pointers that were not deleted. i would like something that can show me what i haven't deleted and i should. thx

Comment: Like he said, valgrind does that.

Comment: And that is exactly the answer that Als gave you.

Comment: that's called a memory leak, not lack

Comment: @skywak: I updated the link in the answer, so that now it takes you to Valgrind-Ubuntu, Since you tagged Ubuntu, I believe you need tool for Ubuntu platform.

Answer (score 1):

It is called [Memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). You can use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) (linux only) for memory leaks and invalid read/write.

You can also use [splint](http://www.splint.org/), which is [static code analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_code_analysis) tool. But it is used to find another class of errors in the code.