# C++ how to find memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I am developing an application in C++ using visual studio 2015 Community Ed. My app runs pretty well at first but within a few minutes it begins to grind to a halt. This says to me that it is a memory leakage. I've gone through the code following the advice given in the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261201/how-to-find-memory-leak-in-a-c-code-project) question. I've looked at [deleaker](http://www.deleaker.com/order.html) as suggested but it runs for $100 which I'd rather not spend if possible. At the current rate it is running my app never exits so using the CRT library as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf(v=vs.140).aspx) doesn't seem feasible. Has any one found any good 'live' profilers particularly good for finding where a memory leak occurs on windows that are free (Preferably something that works with VS2015)?

Comment: Try using `valgrind`.

Comment: @EliSadoff Valgrind is not available for Windows.

Comment: Don't use constructs that are prone to memory leaks, i.e. raw pointer usage, usage of `new[]`, etc.  Using containers, smart pointers, RAII, etc. reduces or totally eliminates memory leaks.  I've never had to diagnose a memory leak in a few years, all due to using the techniques described.

Comment: @OnMyLittleDuck Well, [this is SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows). ;-)

Comment: It sounds like it could be a leak, but have you actually verified that is the problem?

Comment: When was the code last running without this slow-down, and what changes have you made since then? (You have been testing the code, haven't you?)

Comment: I recommend you look at the debug heap in Visual Studio.  crtdbg.h in a debug build will detect leaks.  After `main()` exits it will enumerate all heap allocations that were not allocated by the CRT itself.  I recommend using it in all compilation units to get the most complete report.  It does a lot more than leak detection (e.g. writing over de-allocated memory, heap corruption, writing beyond a memory allocation). [This article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx) is a great place to start for the leak detection capability.

Comment: `//stdafx.h includes
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <crtdbg.h>
` and `int wmain()
{
 _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF|_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_REPORT_FLAG));
 auto leaked_mem = new char[5];
}` will report `Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{112} normal block at 0x00E5EAB8, 5 bytes long.
 Data: <     > CD CD CD CD CD 
Object dump complete.`

Comment: VLD can help with this: https://vld.codeplex.com/