# How do I solve this memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I am trying to recreate the vector class and I believe there is a memory leak in my code, but I don't know how to solve it. Using the CRT Library in my Visual Studio, it tells me that there is a supposed memory leak that doubles for each time that reserve is called.

I am not quite sure why that is or if there even is a memory leak. The memory leak detection says that it is this line in the reserve function **int* temp = new int[n];**

This is what I understand to be happening in the reserve function:

Once the contents of arr are copied into temp, it's fine to delete arr. Assigning **arr = temp** should work because all I'm doing is making arr point to the same place as temp. Because arr was previously deleted, I only have 1 array in the heap and arr and temp both point to the same array so there should be no memory leak. Temp shouldn't matter because it disappears after it exits the scope. On subsequent calls to the reserve function, every thing repeats and there should only be one array in the heap which arr points to.

I do believe that my thinking is probably erroneous in some way.

```
    #include "Vector.h"

    namespace Vector {

    vector::vector() {
        sz = 0;
        space = 0;
        arr = nullptr;
    }
    vector::vector(int n) {
        sz = n;
        space = n;
        arr = new int[n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            arr[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    void vector::push_back(int x) {
        if(sz == 0) {
            reserve(1);
        } else if (sz == space) {
            reserve(2*space);
        }
        arr[sz] = x;
        sz++;
    }
    void vector::reserve(int n) {
        if (n == 1) {
            arr = new int[1]; //arr was a nullptr beforehand
        }
        int* temp = new int[n]; 
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            temp[i] = arr[i];
        }
        delete[] arr;
        arr = temp;
        space = n;      
    }
```

Comment: what if i call `x.reserve(10); x.reserve(1);` ?

Comment: A destructor to free the memory when the `Vector` is destroyed wouldn't hurt. But once you add that don't forget about the [Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: Keep an eye out for `for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) { temp[i] = arr[i]; }` when `space` is smaller than `n`.

Comment: Think about it -- your `reserve` function defeats its own purpose if the amount to reserve is *less than or equal to* the amount that is already reserved.  You should just be returning if the requested amount is less than the current reserve.  We also need to see a [mcve], demonstrating *how* you are generating this memory leak.  It is very simple for us to take your code and break your `vector` class, but we need to see how *you* broke it.

Comment: `//arr was a nullptr beforehand`. No, call `reserve(1)` twice for example.

Comment: You might find answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261201/how-to-find-memory-leak-in-a-c-code-project) question helpful

Answer (score 2):

Your code assumes in `vector::reserve(int n)` that `arr` is `null`.

Instead maybe spilt up how `reserve` functions based on whether or not `arr` is `null`.

```
void vector::reserve(int n) {
    if (arr) { //handle case when arr is null
        space += n;
        arr = new int[space];
        //no need to copy anything!
    } else { //handle case when arr is not null
        int* tmp(new int[space + n]);
        for(int i = 0; i < space; i++) {
            tmp[i] = arr[i];
        }
        delete[] arr;
        arr = tmp;
        space += n;
    }
}
```

Also the above code assumes you mean to reserve `space+n` instead of allowing `reserve` to shrink the array as you'll lose data if you reserve less then a previous reserve. It's usually better practice to not use assumptions about a pointer's state when working with them because when your code gets more complex the assumptions can end up getting forgotten or more obscure.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issues too. I have created two pointers that points in the same address in heap. When I'm trying too deallocate the memory, and the result is only one pointer that can do that, it's the first pointers that point that address. The second or third pointers that points that address doesn't have an authority to deallocate the memory, but only the first pointers who have that authority.

Example

```
int *a = new int[5];
int *b = a;
int *c = a;
```

Pointers b and c doesn't have an authority too dealloacte the memory address that pointers a pointed. Therefore, the memory wasn't deallocated if i'm saying `delete[] b` nor `delete[] c`, they didn't have an authority for doing that. Then I tried to write `delete [] a` and that worked.  I don't have an real answers, and I just trying to approaching through my try and errors that I have done. And that's what I got.

Actually this case is violating the rules, but C++ still allowed us to do it, it's called *undefined behaviors*. We are violating the rules of `delete[]` operators by, but C++ still allowed you to do, and as the result, you get unexpected output.

Comment: You could use any or `a`, `b`, or `c` in your example to delete the allocated object; you just can't do it twice. You're not only limited by using `a` as your answer suggests. It's the value that `a`, `b`, and `c` hold that can only be used once not the variable itself.

Answer (score 0):

Not too much wrong in there.

## Bugs

```
    if (n == 1) {
        arr = new int[1]; //arr was a nullptr beforehand
    }
```

The comment cannot be guaranteed. Nothing prevents multiple calls of resize including a call of `reserve(1)`, and that will leak whatever memory was pointed at by `arr`. Instead consider

```
    if (arr == nullptr) {
        arr = new int[n]; //arr was a nullptr beforehand
    }
```

now the comment is guaranteed to be true.

The copy loop overshoots the end of `arr` every time the size of the array is increased.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        temp[i] = arr[i];
    }
```

`arr` is only good up to `arr[sz-1]`. If `n` is greater than `space`, and it almost always will be, `arr[i]` wanders into the great wilds of [Undefined  Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). Not a good place to go.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < n && i < sz; i++) {
        temp[i] = arr[i];
    }
```

Checks both `n` and `sz` to prevent overrun on either end and copying of data that has not been set yet. If there is nothing to be copied, all done.

## Targets of opportunity

The class needs a destructor to release any memory that it owns ([What is ownership of resources or pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024982/what-is-ownership-of-resources-or-pointers)) when it is destroyed. Without it, you have a leak.

```
vector::~vector() {
    delete[] arr;
}
```

And if it has a destructor, the [Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) requires it to have special support functions to handle (at least) copying of the class or expressly forbid copying.

```
// exchanges one vector for the other. Generally useful, but also makes moves 
// and assignments easy
void vector::swap(vector& a, vector& b)
{
    std::swap(a.sz, b.sz);
    std::swap(a.space, b.space);
    std::swap(a.arr, b.arr);
}

// Copy constructor
vector::vector(const vector& src):
    sz(src.sz),
    space (src.space),
    arr(new int[space])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        arr[i] = src.arr[i];
    }
}

// move constructor
vector::vector(vector&& src): vector()
{
    swap(*this, src);
}

// assignment operator
vector::vector& vector::operator=(vector src)
{
    swap(*this, src);

    return *this;
}
```

The Copy Constructor uses a [Member Initializer List](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list). That's the funny `:` bit.

The assignment operator makes use of the [Copy and Swap Idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom). This isn't the fastest way to implement the assignment operator, but it is probably the easiest. Start with easy and only go to hard if easiest doesn't meet the requirements.