# Detecting Memory Leaks in C++ Windows application

Tags: c++, windows

I have a C++ windows application which has some memory leak issues. Is it possible to analyze the memory leak from the dump using NTSD ? If so please guide me how to do that ?

I have also heard that we can do it using User Mode Dump. I am not very familiar with finding leaks in windows. It is very easy in Linux with Valgrind.

Is there any other better options to check this ?

Comment: are looking for any tool to investigating memory leaks on windows?

Comment: Would Application Verifier (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20028) be of help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual C++ - Memory Leak Detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820223/visual-c-memory-leak-detection)

Comment: Please spend more time searching in the future - duplicate was easy to find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[see here](http://vld.codeplex.com/) for details about Visual Leak Detector. I have used it on Windows.
all you do in your application is to

```
#include <vld.h>
```

and you will see a report about detected leaks in terminal when debugging your program, something like this:

```
---------- Block 1199 at 0x04BE1058: 136 bytes ----------
Call Stack:
d:\Foobar\FooLog.cpp (26): FooLog::getInstance
d:\Foobar\FooMain.cpp (75): FooMain::init
f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtexe.c (578): __tmainCRTStartup
f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtexe.c (403): WinMainCRTStartup
0x759A3677 (File and line number not available): BaseThreadInitThunk
0x770C9D42 (File and line number not available): RtlInitializeExceptionChain
0x770C9D15 (File and line number not available): RtlInitializeExceptionChain
Data:
9C 33 2D 6B    74 2A 2D 6B    C8 11 BE 04    00 00 00 00     .3-kt*-k ........
00 00 00 00    70 14 BB 6C    70 14 BB 6C    00 00 00 00     ....p..l p..l....
00 00 00 00    68 14 BB 6C    68 14 BB 6C    00 00 00 00     ....h..l h..l....
00 00 00 00    6C 14 BB 6C    6C 14 BB 6C    20 12 BE 04     ....l..l l..l....
00 00 00 00    CD 00 CD CD    00 00 00 00    01 CD CD CD     ........ ........
68 14 BB 6C    78 33 2D 6B    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     h..lx3-k ........
```

Comment: I will go through this VLD. I hope this will be useful in multi-threaded application also.

Comment: Never heard about VLD before. 4 minutes later I know I have no memory leaks, sweet! I do recommend it!

Answer (score 1):

I've had great success tracking down memory and resource leaks with [DrMemory](https://github.com/DynamoRIO/drmemory). It works with both GCC and MSVC and it's very straight forward to use.

Comment: Thanks for the portable solution. Will definitely go through this.